# PostgreSQL Upsert Error when specify the table name

Tags: postgresql

im tryign to upsert on PostgreSQL using this query

```
insert into users (id,name) values (1,'henry')
on conflict (users.id) do update set
(id,name)=(EXCLUDED.id,EXCLUDED.name)
```

and keep getting this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 2: on conflict (users.id) do update set
```

it works if i do it this way

```
insert into users (id,name) values (1,'henry')
on conflict (id) do update set
(id,name)=(EXCLUDED.id,EXCLUDED.name)
```

how to specify the table name on the query? like `users.id`

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? You need version 9.5 or later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot qualify the column name with the table name in the `ON CONFLICT` clause; the syntax forbids it:

> where `conflict_target` can be one of:
>
> `( { index_column_name | ( index_expression ) } [ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [, ...] ) [ WHERE index_predicate ]`
>
> `ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name`

You are using the `index_column_name` syntax, so it must look just like in `CREATE INDEX`, where the table name is also not allowed.

There is no need to add the table name, because the can be only one table.